# Submit button ignoring jQuery function associated with it. How to fix?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I'm building a site for a new client and I can't get my head around why the site is completely ignoring the jQuery script and function associated with clicking the "Submit" button on the form.

This is the code of the button:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("It worked!");
    });
});
```

Not only is it **not** preventing the default submit action, it's not even popping up the alert to confirm it worked.

I've tried using `$("form").submit(function (e)` { instead of `$("#submit").click(function (e) {` but it still didn't work.

How can I get the submit button to run and obey the jQuery code associated with it?

**UPDATE:**

It's strange that the code above works on jsfiddle.net but not on the site. I'm including jQuery correctly: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'>‌​‌​. I don't see any relevant errors in the console. jQuery is also referenced correctly because I tried only alert("text"); in the ready function and it worked. So the problem must be specifically with the Submit button. Something must be interfering with it. What could it be?

Comment: Have you seen in console for `errors` ????

Comment: the script looks good. Is it possible you fire the script before loading the jquery.js?

Comment: Have you tried only `alert("text")` in you ready function? If that isn't working, you've referenced your jQuery wrong.

Comment: You can try removing the type. If you want to write your own custom functionality.

Comment: @AkshayPaghdar: I don't see any relevant errors in the console.

Comment: @driedoezoe: No, it's fired after loading jQuery.

Comment: @Niklas: I tried that and it correctly pop-ups the alert, so jQuery is referenced correctly.  What else could be causing this issue?

Comment: @Learner: I just tried removing the type, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @KatieTheBeginner - What happens if you rename the submit button id from `submit` to `mySubmitButton`. Just to see if something is interfering with the id `submit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as expected. u can check the demo here jsfiddle.net/mannejkumar/34PKn/
see javascript console to check jquery is included properly or not

Comment: Strange that it works on jsfiddle.net but not on the site.  I'm including jQuery correctly: `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>`.  What else could be causing this problem?

Comment: yeah, I bet your console says $ is undefined ;p

Comment: Then download jquery in your local machine and include that path.

Comment: @Jagadeesh: I don't see any relevant errors in the console.  jQuery is referenced correctly because I tried only `alert("text");` in the ready function and it worked.  The problem is specifically with the Submit button.  Something must be interfering with it.  What could it be?

Comment: use console.log('Submit',$("#submit")) $("#submit").live('click',function(e){alert('test')});

Comment: @Jagadeesh: How do I do that?  (I'm assuming you're referring to the Firefox console in developer tools?)

Comment: If you are using chrome u can see the console by pressing F12. then console tab in the development tools

Comment: @Jagadeesh: OK, I see the console in Chrome. How do I do the console.log you mentioned?

Comment: Enter console.log('Submit',$("#submit")) in console and see you are getting button element or not

Comment: @Jagadeesh: OK, I found the problem.  It was a syntax error.  Strangely, it wasn't caught by the Firefox console, but it was found by the Chrome console.  I'll be using the Chrome console from now on!  Thanks Jagadeesh!

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this button:

```
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

And use this at the top of the page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Check demo

http://jsfiddle.net/cN5md/

Comment: I just tried that and the Submit button doesn't do anything when clicked, not even the pop-up alert.

Comment: I added the Demo to my answer. It's working. Did you included JavaScript to your File?

Comment: Strange that it works on jsfiddle.net but not on the site. I'm including jQuery correctly: `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>‌​‌​`. I don't see any relevant errors in the console. jQuery is referenced correctly because I tried only `alert("text");` in the ready function and it worked. The problem is specifically with the Submit button. Something must be interfering with it. What could it be?

Comment: You are including an old version of JQuery. Try it with mine URL. That's the only difference I see here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me.

Try using jquery .on() function if you are adding the elements to the DOM asynchronously

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(){
   alert("It works");
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WcGj6/

Comment: @KatieTheBeginner , I am at a loss for what to do, as it works fine in fiddle but not at your site.

Answer (score 0):

It just worked to me (IE8, Chrome, Fx...). Compare mine (the smallest one) with yours.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>  
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("It worked!");
    });
  });  
  </script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Strange that it works on jsfiddle.net but not on the site. I'm including jQuery correctly: `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>‌`​. I don't see any relevant errors in the console. jQuery is referenced correctly because I tried only `alert("text");` in the ready function and it worked. The problem is specifically with the Submit button. Something must be interfering with it. What could it be?